# Bash Shell list files using "for" loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I use the following Bash Shell script to list the ".txt" files recursively under the current directory :

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $( find . -type f -name "*.txt" )
do
  echo $file
  # Do something else.
done
```

However, some of the ".txt" files under the current directory have spaces in their names, e.g. "my testing.txt". The listing becomes corrupted, e.g. "my testing.txt" is listed as

```
my
testing.txt
```

It seems that the "for" loop uses "white space" (space, \n etc) to separate the file list but in my case I want to use only "\n" to separate the file list.

Is there any way I could modify this script to achieve this purpose. Any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In bash, I think you use `find ... -print0` and `IFS="\0"`, or thereabouts.  There are definitely other questions on this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using bash 4, just use a glob:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

shopt -s globstar

for file in **/*.txt
do
  if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]
  then
      continue
  fi
  echo "$file"
  # Do something else.                                                          
done
```

Be sure to quote `"$file"` or you'll have the same problem elsewhere. `**` will recursively match files and directories if you have enabled `globstar`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, have `find` separate the file names with NUL and use `read` to delimit on `NUL`. This will successfully iterate over any file name since NUL is not a valid character for a file name.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  echo "$file"
  # Do something else.
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0)
```

Alternatively, if the `# do something else` is not too complex, you can use `find`'s `-exec` option and not have to worry about proper delimiting

Comment: Thanks. But the method seems less familiar to me. I'll try it later.

Comment: The idiomatic use of `find` is something like this.  The problem with `for file in $(find ...)` is precisely that it will split on whitespace.  Instead, use `find ... | while read file`.  The additional options to `read` are required to properly cope with even file names with newlines, but if all you need to cope with is spaces, you can be a bit flimsier.

Comment: This method is a good alternative solution for my case as it allows arbitrary allowable file names. The method is now tested OK and works for my case too.

Comment: @user1129812 To add what @tripleee said, the reason why I didn't pipe the output of `find` but instead used process substitution `<()` is because the latter doesn't create a subshell so any variables you might alter inside the while-loop can be accessed outside. This may be important if say you want to keep a counter of how many files you iterated through and access that counter elsewhere in the script.

Comment: @SiegeX I see your point. `find ... | while read file` would leave the `while` loop in a subshell whose variables could not be seen in the calling shell. Anyway, both solution works for my case. Thanks SiegeX and tripleee.