# bash scripts list files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script that takes an argument which is a directory .
i want to be able to construct list/array with all the files that have a certain extension in that directory and cut their extension . 
For example if i have directory containing :

- aaa.xx
- bbb.yy
- ccc.xx

and im searching for *.xx .
my list/array would be :  aaa ccc.
I'm trying to use the code in this thread [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139214/bash-shell-list-files-using-for-loop) the accepted answer .

```
set tests_list=[]

for f in $1/*.bpt
do
   echo $f
   if [[ ! -f "$f" ]]
   then
      continue
   fi
   set tmp=echo $f | cut -d"." -f1
   #echo $tmp
   tests_list+=$tmp                                                         
done

echo ${tests_list[@]}
```

if i run this script i get that the loop only executes once with $f is tests_list=[]/*.bpt which is weird since $f should be a file name in that directory , and echo empty string.
i validated that i'm in the correct directory and that the argument directory have files with .bpt extensions .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over files in directory with bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-directory-with-bash)

Comment: its not duplicate , did you read the whole question ? i need to build list with only the names of the files and cut all extensions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filear=($(find path/ -name "*\.xx"))
filears=()
for f in ${filear[@]}; do filears[${#filears[@]}]=${f%\.*}; done
```

Comment: it kinda worked , but my files have spaces ,so echo ${filears[1]} prints a word in a file name not the whole file name .

Comment: `${f%\.*}` just strips the file ending use $f to get the whole filename stored. for the space problem just change the IFS=$'\n' or whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
for file in *.xx ; do echo "${file%.*}" ; done
```

To expand this to a script that takes an argument as a directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"
ext='xx'

for file in "$dir"/*."$ext"
do
    echo "${file%.*}"
done
```

edit: switched `ls` with `for` - thanks @tripleee for the correction.

Comment: The `ls` is [useless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) or [worse](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  You mean `for file in *.xx` and `for file in "$dir"/*."$ext"`

Comment: `for file in *.xx` will split filenames with spaces in them, so no I don't mean either of your suggestions. But, I would say `find` would be better. Also, you linked to useless use of cat, what's the relevance..?

Comment: That is completely incorrect. It will loop over the matching filenames one by one. If you experience a problem, is is because you fail to quote `"$file"` properly inside the loop (but you have proper quoting in your examples).

Comment: UULS is easy to lump with UUCA and other similar antipatterns. But here, then: http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls

Comment: @tripleee - You are right, sorry! Apologies. I really did think `for ...` split words for some reason, I stand corrected.